# It does not work relationship nested resources rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some problem with relationship in rails. My application has the relationship between the publisher and the Website.

When I add a site to the publisher using `f.collection_select` relationship is working properly. However, if I create a nested routing and am using

```
localhost:3000/publishers/8/sites/new

<% = Link_to ("Add site", new_publisher_site_path (publisher), class "btn btn-default navbar-btn")%

def new
  @publisher = Publisher.find(params[:publisher_id])
  @site = Site.new 
end
```

It does not form a relationship.

Comment: Please mention the relationships between your models here :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming relationship between publisher and site as publisher `has_many :sites`, and site `belongs_to :publisher` :

Do this in your site controller:

```
 def new 
   @publisher = Publisher.find(params[:publisher_id])
   @site = @publisher.sites.new
 end

 def create
   @publisher = Publisher.find(params[:publisher_id])
   @site = @publisher.sites.new(sites_params)
   if @site.save
      redirect_to publishers_path
   else
     render 'new'
   end
 end
```

Comment: `@publisher.sites.new` will not save a record in your database. It just creates a instance of Site with publisher_id as id of @publisher. If you want to insert this record in the database, save it. Do `@site.save`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean relationship between models `Site` and `Publisher` you should use `has_many`, `has_one`, `belongs_to` or other associations [rails assosiations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

and then you can write:

```
def new 
  @publisher = Publisher.find(params[:publisher_id])
  @site = @publisher.sites // sites only associated with Publisher.find(params[:publisher_id])
end
```